# Why is Rules Action "Create Linked Drupal User Account" not working?

Tags: 7, users, rules

I’m using Drupal **7.56** and CiviCRM **4.6.31**.

I’ve been using Rules in Drupal to create a Drupal User Account linked to the CiviCRM contact created.
But it's failing. I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot create user, email: invalid!!

This is the **export** of the Rule:

```
{ "rules_create_a_drupaluser_for_an_civicrmcontact" :
    {
        "LABEL" : "Create a Drupal user for an CiviCRM contact",
        "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
        "OWNER" : "rules",
        "REQUIRES" : [ "civicrm" ],
        "ON" : { "civicrm_contact_create" : [] },
        "IF" : [
          { "NOT civicrm_entity_user_exists" : { "civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm_contact" ] } }
        ],
        "DO" : [
          {
            "civicrm_entity_action_create_user" : {
              "USING" : {
                "civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm_contact" ],
                "is_active" : "1",
                "notify" : "0",
                "signin" : "0",
                "username_format" : "email"
              },
              "PROVIDE" : { "civicrm_user" : { "civicrm_user" : "Created Drupal User" } }
            }
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

It was working some time ago.

The link where I downloaded the civicrm_entity (release 7.x-2.0) is:
*https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity/releases*

For your convenience I've added the source code for the Rules Action `civicrm_entity_action_create_user`:

```
function civicrm_entity_action_create_user ($contact, $is_active, $notify = FALSE, $signin = FALSE, $username_format = 'first last') {

  if (!is_array($contact)) {

    // Perhaps we should be accepting object rather than array here?
    $contact = (array) $contact;
  }

  // We'll use the civicrm sync mechanism to see if Civi can match the
  // contact to an existing user.

  // Don't think this is a great approach but will use for now - could
  // just create the user but no great support for that yet.

  if (empty($contact['display_name']) || empty($contact['email']) || empty($contact['first_name']) || empty($contact['last_name'])) {

    $contact = civicrm_api('contact', 'getsingle', array(
      'version' => 3,
      'id' => $contact['id'],
      'sequential' => 1,
      'return' => 'email,display_name,first_name,last_name',
    ));
  }

  if (!is_string($contact['email']) && isset($contact['email'][0]->email)) {

    $contact['email'] = $contact['email'][0]->email;
  }

  // @TODO What happens if they don't have an email at this point?

  // An email is a pre-requisite for a Drupal account, so the action
  // fails if they don't have an email.

  if (filter_var($contact['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {

    drupal_set_message(filter_xss("Cannot create user, email: " . $contact['email'] . " invalid!!") , 'error');

    watchdog('civicrm_entity', 'Cannot create user, email %mail invalid.', array('%mail' => $contact['email']), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    return FALSE;
  }
```

And here is where the error raises.

These is the **Rules evaluation log**:

```
Reacting on event CiviCRM Contact has been created.

 Evaluating conditions of rule Create a Drupal user for an CiviCRM contact. 

 The condition civicrm_entity_user_exists evaluated to FALSE

 AND evaluated to TRUE.

Rule Create a Drupal user for an CiviCRM contact fires.

   Rule Create a Drupal user for an CiviCRM contact fires.

   Evaluating the action civicrm_entity_action_create_user.

   Evaluating the action devel_debug.

   Rule Create a Drupal user for an CiviCRM contact has fired.

Finished reacting on event CiviCRM Contact has been created.
```

And the Log Message gets this Error:

```
MESSAGE "**Cannot create user, email invalid.**"
```

Does anyone have any clue about what might be happening?

Comment: Please include a link to where you downloaded that  CiviCRM 4.6.31 from. I'd like to see the source code related to that rules action civicrm_entity_action_create_use. On top of that, please include a "rules debugging log" (to see what happens after your Rules Condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the issue you're facing is within the comment lines of the Rules Action you included iin your question, i.e.:

```
  // @TODO What happens if they don't have an email at this point?

  // An email is a pre-requisite for a Drupal account, so the action
  // fails if they don't have an email.
```

The eMail ID for the CiviCRM contact you're using appears to be missing. So try again with a similar testcase, but make sure that for the CiviCRM contact some eMail Id is entered.

This probably also explains the "*It was working some time ago*": chances are that it was working, since you were using a CiviCRM contact for which an eMail ID was available.